# Connecting Oracle via SSIS failed due to error ORA-01019

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a problem with SSIS that I cannot figure it out what is wrong!

2 days back I used Microsoft oracle connection component to connect oracle database that **it was successful.**

I also tried with my Oracle Oracle connection component to connect to oracle database(odp) which **this one was also successful.**

Suddenly in the evening, I face with below issue. what could be the reason. It is so funny for both Oracle and Microsoft connection component I am receiving a similar issue.

Please take note that in the package I was working there is an oracle connection and MSSQL connection. I feel that after using MSSQL connecting this issue occur. but even when I created a new package with a single Oracle connection, I am facing the same issue again.

Please take note that I can connect to my oracle database via SQL developer successfully.

> ### TITLE: Connection Manager
>
> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

My system information:

> ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0 ProjectServicesPackage Visual
>   Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services   14.0.1016.285 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Analysis Services Designer  Version 14.0.1016.285
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61801.210 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
>   Services Designer Version 14.0.3002.92
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services   14.0.1016.285 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Reporting Services Designers  Version 14.0.1016.285
>
> SsmsVsIntegration   1.0 Information about my package
>
> Visual Basic Tools   2.7.0-beta3-62715-05. Commit Hash:
>   db02128e6e3c4bdfc93e6ec425ac9162b4d4fe80 Visual Basic components used
>   in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different
>   version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>   my system environment variables:

[image]

Comment: *"Suddenly in the evening, I face with below issue"* This means that something in your environment **changed** in the last two days. You have a different configuration - client libraries, multiple Oracle Homes, corrupt registries. Either it's something you did or something your colleagues did. Once you establish what the change was it will be easier for you to reverse it (or workaround it).

Comment: @APC: I am the only one using the server and I am sure nothing update or installed!

Comment: Sorry, but something has changed. Oracle won't suddenly start throwing ORA-01019 for no reason.

Comment: @APC: by any chance can u look at my env variable please? I added ORACLE_home='D:\instantclient_12_2' but no change...

Answer (score 2):

From [Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_error_while_trying_to_retrieve_text.htm)

It might be caused by multiple 32 bit client libraries on your machine or more than one ORACLE_HOME path in System Variables.

Comment: I edit my question, can you check do I have multiple client library in my environment variable?

Comment: @Amir What do 11.2.0\client_1 and 12.1.0\client_1 refer to? Both 32-bit driver? If so, this will be the root cause. See: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108342/two-oracle-clients-on-the-same-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108342/two-oracle-clients-on-the-same-server)